# when I use resourcePrefix attribute in gradle config, how to exclude dependencies lib at lint check?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I configure the resourcePrefix property in a module build.gradle, lint checks the dependency library when I build it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W92i.png)

I want to retain this property, but I want lint not to check the libraries that depend on them. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android studio, the lint option can be customized via the menu option Analyze -> Inspect code -> custom scope

Reference : https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#studio_config (see "Set the inspection scope and profile")

Comment: I have no way to find the set, I want the resourcePrefix attribute is valid only for my own code (because there are a number of modules, in order to prevent the resource name conflict), but does not check the dependent libraries (such as in the log information of google-services resources)